# Converting a Datetime column to a DatetimeIndex in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

There are so many questions that revolve around converting dates to a datetimeindex. I personally need a datetimeindex to work with the Calmap package that requires the datetimeindex. After following many stackoverflow guides, I haven't been able to change my date fields to a datetimeindex. Here are the following steps I took.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
##I also attempted to add parse_dates=["Date'] and Index["Date"] to the pd.read_csv() 
main_data = pd.read_csv('newoutput2.csv', delimiter=",", encoding='cp1252')
main_data =  main_data.set_index(pd.to_datetime(main_data["Date"], format = "%m/%d/%y"))
import calmap
events = pd.Series(main_data.index)
calmap.yearplot(events, year=2020)

##When I run events[0] the output is
##Timestamp('2020-10-05 00:00:00')
```

The error I receive after running that code is

```
python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\calmap\__init__.py in yearplot(data, year, how, vmin, vmax, cmap, fillcolor, linewidth, linecolor, daylabels, dayticks, monthlabels, monthticks, ax, **kwargs)
    141         # Sample by day.
    142         if _pandas_18:
--> 143             by_day = data.resample("D").agg(how)
    144         else:
    145             by_day = data.resample("D", how=how)

TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'
```

No matter the format I follow, it never seems to create a datetimeindex from the data.

The data is here

[image: CSV data, loaded in excel]

The original data

```
Name    Time    Date
FName LName 12:00PM     10/5/20
FName LName 12:00PM     10/5/20
FName LName 12:00PM     10/5/20
FName LName 12:00PM     10/5/20
FName LName 12:00PM     10/5/20
FName LName 12:00PM     10/5/20
FName LName 12:00PM     10/5/20
```

If I print main_data, it appears like this

```
    Name    Time    Date
Date            
2020-10-05  FName LName 12:00:00    10/5/20
2020-10-05  FName LName 12:00:00    10/5/20
2020-10-05  FName LName 12:00:00    10/5/20
2020-10-05  FName LName 12:00:00    10/5/20
2020-10-05  FName LName 12:00:00    10/5/20
```

Comment: The index needs to be a DateTime index, right now your values are date times. You'll need to pass the index properly: `events = pd.Series(index=main_data.index)`

Answer (score 0):

Try concat Date and Time before setting index. `Use df.column.str.cat(colum1, sep=' ')`

print(df)

```
     Name     Time     Date
0  FName LName  12:00PM  10/5/20
1  FName LName  12:00PM  10/5/20
2  FName LName  12:00PM  10/5/20
3  FName LName  12:00PM  10/5/20
4  FName LName  12:00PM  10/5/20
5  FName LName  12:00PM  10/5/20
6  FName LName  12:00PM  10/5/20


df['datetime']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].str.cat(df.Time, sep=' '))
df.set_index(df['datetime'], inplace=True)
print(df)

            

                      Name     Time     Date            datetime
datetime                                                              
2020-10-05 12:00:00  FName LName  12:00PM  10/5/20 2020-10-05 12:00:00
2020-10-05 12:00:00  FName LName  12:00PM  10/5/20 2020-10-05 12:00:00
2020-10-05 12:00:00  FName LName  12:00PM  10/5/20 2020-10-05 12:00:00
2020-10-05 12:00:00  FName LName  12:00PM  10/5/20 2020-10-05 12:00:00
2020-10-05 12:00:00  FName LName  12:00PM  10/5/20 2020-10-05 12:00:00
2020-10-05 12:00:00  FName LName  12:00PM  10/5/20 2020-10-05 12:00:00
2020-10-05 12:00:00  FName LName  12:00PM  10/5/20 2020-10-05 12:00:00
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and it still gives the same output. ``` Name: datetime, Length: 7170, dtype: datetime64[ns]  ```